# Python selenium webdriver couldn't find element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My python Selenium program could not find the frame in which I think the web-element is residing. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you.

---

```
# switch back to main window
driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("header");
driver.find_element_by_id("a_1").click()
time.sleep(10)

# switch back to main window
driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("contents");               ***<----- failed here***
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.window("itreecontrol");
time.sleep(5)
# Click on desired item
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click()
```

[image]

===============================

Additional issue: Cannot find element on popped-up window

```
# switch back to main window
driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("header");
driver.find_element_by_id("a_1").click()
time.sleep(10)

# Go to correct frame first
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("contents");
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"));
time.sleep(5)
# Click on plus icon to pop up a window
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click()

# Enter your info in this text-field element in the popped-up window
# (failed to find "unitName-inputEl" here)
driver.find_element_by_id("unitName-inputEl").clear()       <--- failed here
```

### Updated code -1

```
# switch back to main window
driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)   
# Click on 'Firewall' panel
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("header");
driver.find_element_by_id("a_1").click()
time.sleep(10)

# switch to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
# Go to the correct frame first
driver.switch_to.frame("contents");
driver.switch_to.frame("itreecontrol");
time.sleep(5)
# Click on plus-box icon to display pop-up
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("unitName-inputEl").clear()
#driver.find_element_by_id("unitName-inputEl").send_keys("tz400")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "unitName-inputEl"))).send_keys('tz400')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After switching to `<iframe id="header">` you need to switch back to *default content* to be able to switch to `<iframe id="contents">`

try:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("header");
driver.find_element_by_id("a_1").click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("contents")
driver.switch_to.frame("itreecontrol")
```

To handle `input` field you can try to use `ExplicitWait` as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "unitName-inputEl"))).send_keys('tz4‌​00')
```

Comment: Thanks Anderson. It worked. I have an additional issue though.
After that, a window pops up for me to fill in all the text fields with information. I cannot find any elements in the popped-up window.
(

Comment: When you switched to `iframe` with `id="contents"`, you should then switch to embedded `iframe` with `id="itreecontrol"`

Comment: I did it as follows, but it still failed to find element "unitName-inputEl" with send_keyṣ(). Am I doing something wrong?
    


`driver.switch_to.default_content()`
    # Go to the correct frame first
    driver.switch_to.frame("contents");
    driver.switch_to.frame("itreecontrol");
    time.sleep(5)
    # Click on plus icon to display pop up window
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click()

    driver.find_element_by_id("unitName-inputEl").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("unitName-inputEl").send_keys("tz400")

Comment: What this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click‌​() ` should do? How does the pop-up looks like? What exception you get?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a/span/span/span").click‌​‌​() 
is supposed to click on an icon which will pop-up a dialog window for me to fill in information.

Comment: So `input` field isn't present in `DOM` till you click on icon to open pop-up?

Comment: Correct, the input element "unitName-inputEl" does not show up until the popped-up window is displayed. It's a field inside the popped-up window.

Comment: Check updated answer and let me know if issue still persist

Comment: Still failed. See updated code and error log image above.

Comment: Try to replace `EC.element_to_be_clickable` with `EC.visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Still failed with visibility_of_element_located. See latest error log image.

Comment: try `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("unitName-inputEl")))`. Does it returns `2`?

Comment: Will run it again tomorrow, system is currently down.